# An item with the same key has already been added error even when i clear

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have this lines of code inside a FormMain_load sub.

At the first load, the program works fine. Then I try opening another form and call the FormMain again. This time, the form showed an error, An item with the same key has already been added. I tried to put a dictionary clear on the first line of the sub, but it still showed the same error. Then I also tried to clear the dictionary before adding it all over again, but it still failed. What is weird is the message box showed that the dictionary count is 0 before the error happened.

```
    query = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE isPaid=0"
    If myConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        myConn.Open()
    End If
    If myCommand Is Nothing Then
        myCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, myConn)
    Else
        myCommand.CommandText = query
    End If
    myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
    If myDataReader.HasRows Then
        While myDataReader.Read()
            transactionUnpaid.Enqueue(myDataReader("transaction_id"))
        End While
        myDataReader.Close()
        roomList.Clear()
        MsgBox(roomList.Count())
        For Each a As Integer In transactionUnpaid
            query = "SELECT * FROM room_ol WHERE transaction_id=" & a
            If myConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                myConn.Open()
            End If
            If myCommand Is Nothing Then
                myCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, myConn)
            Else
                myCommand.CommandText = query
            End If
            myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
            myDataReader.Read()
            roomList.Add(myDataReader("room_id"), myDataReader("transaction_id"))
            myDataReader.Close()
        Next
    End If
    If Not myDataReader.IsClosed Then
        myDataReader.Close()
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to [Fabio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1565525/fabio),[Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3055288/jens), and [Bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6375113/bugs) there. So the problem is I didn't clear the transactionUnpaid Queue, and when I called the FormMain once again, it enqueue some duplicate items (which is allowed in queue), and it made some keys inserted more than once hence the error.